# React.js pending 4 min before gets response from Express.js backand restful api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on a simple page builder app, which uses React on the front-end and Express on the back-end.
As Ajax library I use the Axios npm package. Beneath you can see the code that is relevant for this question:

```
###########
PageList.js
###########
.
.
.
componentDidMount() {
          axios.get('/admin/pages')
          .then(response => {
             console.log(response.data);
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err);
         })
    })
}
.
.
.
```

This is the front-end portion. On the back-end I have router that works what it's meant for, i.e routes me to this controller ( I can see this from the logs on the server side console ):

```
####################
controllers/admin.js
####################
.
.
.
exports.getPages = (req, res, next) => {
    Page.find()
        .then(pages => {
            return pages;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
};
.
.
.
```

Both, front-end as well as the back-end are running on the localhost on windows machine as node apps, running on different ports. I had that CORS issue initially, which I solved it, with the cors npm package. As DB manager I use mongodb with mongoose ODM.

The problem that I have is that when I send an Ajax request to all of the back-end endpoints, the app gets stacked for 4 minutes (exactly, I do not know how come...) in which period the back-end works its job, it logs all the consoles that I set, it writes the document inside DB, if it is a POST request, but it waits 4 minutes before the front-end is prompted that the request had been successful. During this, the request in the dev tools --> network tab, has the status of pending.

I can make a git-hub repo, butt still I haven't hidden all those sensitive information, i.e they are still hard coded on some places in the app, so it is risky to give a public access to the resources that I use.
So, I'd be glad if someone can give me a heads-up on what might be the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like: `.then(pages => res.send(pages))`?

Comment: I'd use the usual debugging tricks, focusing on narrowing down the possible causes of the problem. You could e.g. add a console.log of the current time in exports.getPages before and after the Page.find() call. If that still takes 4 minutes, the problem is somewhere in your Page implementation or Mongodb. Try to issue essentially the same request directly to Mongodb (from command line), both locally on Mongodb host and remotely from the Node host. Etc.

Comment: As @patrick-hund - you missed the res.send(). I bet you are getting timeout after 4 minutes, not successful response.

Comment: Hey, @Patrick Hund ... thanks a lot... totally missed it... It is as you say...

Comment:  glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to actually send the data that you are retrieving from your database. Thus, your server runs into a timeout after 4 minutes.

You can fix this by calling [res.send](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.send) or [res.json](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.json), like this:

```
####################
controllers/admin.js
####################
.
.
.
exports.getPages = (req, res, next) => {
    Page.find()
        .then(pages => res.send(pages))
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
};
.
.
.
```